# ListView Autosize based on whether or not contents exist

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a `ListView` with a view of `View.Details` and I want to AutoSize the columns. I am aware of the `ColumnHeader`'s `AutoResize` method and currently I'm just iterating through them like so:

```
var lMode = ( listView.Items.Count == 0 ) ? ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize : ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent;
foreach ( ColumnHeader lColumnHeader in listView.Columns )
{
    lColumnHeader.AutoResize(lMode);
}
```

The problem with this technique is that if I have a column which happens to have no data in it, the width gets set to a point the header is no longer available. Is there a nice way of conditionally setting the `ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle` based on whether or not there are contents in the column?

If there is something in the column I want to use `ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent`, but if there is nothing in the column, I want to use `ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a method I've been using for a little while now that does not involve measuring strings.

The bool parameter is because I call the method by itself (and set the parameter to true), and sometimes I call it directly after an Items.AddRange(ListViewItem[]) call, in which I'd wrap both calls in the Begin/End Update calls.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Set the column widths to the widest of the items
    /// or the column header text.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="useUpdate">Whether to use Begin/End Update methods
    /// to pause the drawing of the list view.</param>
    private void SetColumnWidths(bool useUpdate)
    {
        if(useUpdate)
            list.BeginUpdate();

        int width;
        int totalWidth = 0;

        foreach (ColumnHeader col in list.Columns)
        {
            // The last column's width will be the leftover
            //   width of the list view.
            if (list.Columns.Count != col.DisplayIndex)
            {
                col.AutoResize(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize); 
                width = col.Width;

                col.AutoResize(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
                if (width > col.Width)
                    col.Width = width;

                totalWidth += col.Width;
            }
            else
            {
                col.Width = (list.ClientSize.Width - totalWidth);
            }

        }

        if(useUpdate)
            list.EndUpdate();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless a better answer is found, let me at least give an answer to my question in case other people want this functionality. The best way I could think of was to manually scan the table and measure the strings myself. I created an extension method for this purpose:

```
public static void AutoResizeAllColumns( this ListView listView )
{
    if ( listView.Columns.Count == 0 ) return;

    var lGraphics = Graphics.FromHwnd( listView.Handle );

    foreach ( ColumnHeader lColumnHeader in listView.Columns )
    {
        var lColumnHeaderTextSize = lGraphics.MeasureString( lColumnHeader.Text, listView.Font );

        var lColumnIndex = lColumnHeader.Index;
        var lAnyContents = listView.Items
            .Cast<ListViewItem>()
            .Select( x => lGraphics.MeasureString( x.SubItems[ lColumnIndex ].Text, listView.Font ) )
            .Any( x => x.Width > lColumnHeaderTextSize.Width );

        lColumnHeader.AutoResize( lAnyContents ? ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent : ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize );
    }
}
```

I have not measured this method for speed or anything, but it seems to work. Just hoping to find a more elegant solution.